# Check whether url exists or not without downloading the content using python

Tags: python, rest, http

I have to check whether url exists or not using python. I am trying to use requests.get(url) but it is taking alot of time as the file starts downloading as soon as get is hit. I don't want the file to be downloaded for checking the url validity. Can this be achieved using python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the below. See HTTP `head` for more info.

```
import requests
urls = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.google.com/you_can_not_find_me']
for idx,url in enumerate(urls,1):
  r = requests.head(url)
  if r.status_code == 200:
    print(f'{idx}) {url} was found')
  else:
    print(f'{idx}) {url} was NOT found')
```

output

```
1) https://www.google.com was found
2) https://www.google.com/you_can_not_find_me was NOT found
```

Comment: Correct way is to check for [404](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) code and catch connection and timeout exceptions. Sometimes website could just return [405](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) or [501](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/501) on HEAD request, but it doesn't mean that path is invalid. Any other error also is not a reliable proof that url does not exist.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I agree - it can be improved..

Comment: @OlvinRoght So is the better option to use get method with `stream=True` rather than the requests.head method ?

Comment: @PeterMoore, in ideal world HEAD is a correct option as that's the method with initially has been created to retrieve just headers. The problem is that some servers just omit implementation of it and isn't processing HEAD requests properly returning wrong response, that's why GET request which drop connection after headers retrieved *(which `stream=True` does)* is a more stable way. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70446485/10824407#comment124532486_70446782) comment I've just suggested to react on `404` response code instead of `200` to not recognize any error as Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

Set a stream 10 byte count -- it's really fast due to no full download

```
import requests

def check_remote_file_exists(file_url):
    r = requests.get(file_url, stream=True, verify=False)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        content = next(r.iter_content(10))
        return True
    else:
        print(f"HTTP Error {r.status_code} - {r.reason}")
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

**To go further of @balderman & @EuroMarkus answers**:

`GET` request with very short download:

##### Code

```
import requests

codes = ('200', '404', '500')
for idx, code in enumerate(codes,1):
    url = 'https://httpstat.us/' + code
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=True)

    if r.status_code >= 200 and r.status_code < 400:
        print(f'{idx}) {url} OK')
        content = next(r.iter_content(10))
    else:
        print(f'{idx}) {url} NOT OK: {r.status_code} - {r.reason}')
```

##### Output

```
1) https://httpstat.us/200 OK
2) https://httpstat.us/404 NOT OK: 404 - Not Found
3) https://httpstat.us/500 NOT OK: 500 - Internal Server Error
```

##### Check https://httpstat.us/ for a list of `HTTP` return codes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you?

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Python_logo_wordmark.png')

if r.status_code == 200:
    choice = input("File available!\nDownload? Y/N: ").capitalize().strip()
    if choice == 'Y':
        with open('aim.png','wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    else:
        print("Good bye!")
```

Comment: Will be perfect to add `stream=True` argument, so `requests` won't download response body until you explicitly ask for it. More detailed explanation you can find in docs: [*Body Content Workflow*](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow). Also if task is to save response body content to file it could be done using [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) with [`Response.raw`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content).